# Cómo instalar librería liblinear en Windows

Tags: javascript, git, github

Aca está el sitio de github https://github.com/cjlin1/liblinear

Acá su sitio principal: http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/

Todo esto lo hago para hacer la prueba de https://github.com/erelsgl/limdu/tree/master/classifiers/svm

El demo

> SvmLinearMulticlassDemo.js

el codigo es:

```
// simple demonstration of multiclass SVM, based on LibLinear

var SvmLinear = require('./SvmLinear');

var trainSet = [
        {input: [0,0], output: 3},
        {input: [1,1], output: 3},

        {input: [0,1], output: 4},
        {input: [1,2], output: 4},

        {input: [0,2], output: 5},
        {input: [1,3], output: 5},
        ];

// One separating line goes through [0,0.5] and [1,1.5]. It is:
//        0.5+x-y = 0
// or:   -1-2x+2y = 0

//Another separating line goes through [0,1.5] and [1,2.5]. It is:
//       1.5+x-y = 0
//or:   -3-2x+2y = 0


var classifier = new SvmLinear(
    {
        learn_args: "-c 20", 
        model_file_prefix: "tempfiles/SvmLinearMulticlassDemo",
        multiclass: true,
        debug: false
    }
);
classifier.trainBatch(trainSet);

console.log("simple classification: ");
console.dir(classifier.classify([1,0]));  // 3
console.dir(classifier.classify([0,1.3]));  // 4
console.dir(classifier.classify([0,1.7]));  // 5
console.dir(classifier.classify([0,3]));  // 5

console.log("model: ");
console.dir(classifier.mapLabelToMapFeatureToWeight);   // { '0': -1, '1': -2, '2': 2 }

console.log("explained classification: ");
console.dir(classifier.classify([1,0],3));  // 3
console.dir(classifier.classify([0,1.3],3));  // 4
console.dir(classifier.classify([0,1.7],3));  // 5
console.dir(classifier.classify([0,3],3));  // 5

console.log("classification with scores: ");
console.dir(classifier.classify([1,0],0,true));  // 3
console.dir(classifier.classify([0,1.3],0,true));  // 4
console.dir(classifier.classify([0,1.7],0,true));  // 5
console.dir(classifier.classify([0,3],0,true));  // 5

console.log("explained classification with scores: ");
console.dir(classifier.classify([1,0],3,true));  // 3
console.dir(classifier.classify([0,1.3],3,true));  // 4
console.dir(classifier.classify([0,1.7],3,true));  // 5
console.dir(classifier.classify([0,3],3,true));  // 5
```

Quiero que me ayuden a ejecutar ese demo. Hice la prueba y me sale error por falta de que no sé cómo instalar la librería que comente arriba.

Comment: @Mariano modifique mi pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Los pasos que deberías seguir para Windows:

- Descarga [los binarios de `liblinear`](https://github.com/cjlin1/liblinear/tree/master/windows) en un directorio en tu sistema local.
- [Agrega a la variable de entorno PATH](https://www.java.com/es/download/help/path.xml) la ruta completa de este directorio.
- [Instala `nodejs`](https://nodejs.org/en/)

Desde aquí tienes 2 opciones:

- [Instalar `Limdu.js`](https://github.com/erelsgl/limdu#installation) en un proyecto actual (`npm install limdu`).
- [Clonar el proyecto `limdu-demo`](https://github.com/erelsgl/limdu-demo) (`git clone https://github.com/erelsgl/limdu-demo.git`)